# TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction;

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc

I face this problem when I update one of the database table fields:

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction"
```

Comment: There has to be more than that in the stack trace...

Comment: That is _very_ little to go on. Tell us a little more about when this happens. Also, show us a little more of the stack trace, and the code where it occurs. Maybe then we can help you diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This may be happening due to number of reasons. But one of the common causes for this problem is to forget annotating one of the methods used in update process as `@Transactional`. Can this be the case by any chance?